# Minimise time of travel (optimisation question)

Tags: optimization, pythagorean-triples

Okay, need some guidance helping child with math homework. An accident has happened and the ambulance needs to get there in the quickest time. Here is the situation (I added `A` through `D` markers):

```
AMBULANCE              40km
A========================B====================C
                         <-------- x -------->|
                                              |
                                              |
                                              | 15km
                  BUSH                        |
                                              |
                                              |
                                              D ACCIDENT
```

The ambulance can do 20km/h on the road `AC` (which is 40km long), and 10km/h in the bush (which is everything *except* the road).

Since we need to minimise the time taken, there's obviously some point `B` along the road where it's faster to go off-road straight to `D` rather than going through `C`. Let's use `x` as the `BC` distance.

So, the time taken to traverse `AB` and `BD` (using Pythagoras for the latter) is:

$$\frac{40 - x}{20} + \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 15^2}}{10}$$

This can be converted into:

$$\frac{40}{20} - \frac{x}{20} + \frac{2\sqrt{x^2 + 15^2}}{20}$$

and further simplified to (since minimising doesn't care about constant additions or common divisors):

$$ 2\sqrt{x^2 + 15^2} - x$$

But I'm not sure where to go from there. Being a computer nerd, I wrote a Python program to calculate the value of `x` that would deliver the minimum (checking zero through forty in `0.01` increments).

I also think (though from *many* years ago) that integral calculus may get me the answer as well.

Unfortunately, my child has done neither of those things in class so I'm not sure they're the correct way to go.

What would be the next step, and are there any other (i.e., simpler) ways to work out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Physics-inclined:

$\def\km{\,\mathrm{km}}$
$\def\kmh{\km/\mathrm{h}}$
[Light knows the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) and it follows [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law):

$$
\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}=\frac{20\kmh}{10\kmh}=2
$$
with the [angles of incidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_incidence_(optics))

- $\alpha=90^°$ is the angle of direction of ambulance on the road (measured against a road's [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)))
- $\beta$ is the angle of direction of ambulance in the bush (measured against a road's normal)

We get $\sin\beta=0.5$ and hence $\beta=\pi/6=30^°$. This means angle $\angle CBD = 60°$ and therefore
$$
\frac{15\km}x = \tan 60° = \sqrt3 \quad\Rightarrow \quad
x=\frac1{\sqrt3}\cdot 15\km = 5\sqrt3\km
\approx 8.66\km.
$$

Because $x\leqslant 40\km$, this is the result.  (If $x\geqslant40\km$ then the best path would be not to use the road at all, and to go 100% bushes.)

Comment: WTH? I'm once again amazed by a photon's ability to sneak up on me and kick me in the rear end. I'll have to look into this one but since you got the same answer I got from brute force, it looks good. In any case, since I'm a gvim guy, you'd get an upvote anyway just because of you moniker :-)

Answer (score 1):

Making the problem more general, you want to minimize
$$f(x)=2\sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - x$$ for which
$$f'(x)=\frac{2 x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac{2 a^2}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^{3/2}}$$ So, the first derivative cancels when
$$2x=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\implies 4x^2=x^2+a^2\implies ???$$

Comment: I assume that's calculus (it's been a while). I don't doubt that would solve it but I was hoping for something a little more "year 10 math"-level. Just on the solution, I think that becomes `3x^2 = 15^2 => x = sqrt(225/3) = sqrt(75) = 5sqrt(3)`, yes? Having said that I'm after a simpler solution if possible, I'll still upvote the calculus answers since they're probably the way to go if you actually know the methods.

Comment: @paxdiablo. This is very correct.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate your expression for time: $T = \frac{40-x}{20}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+15^2}}{10}$

Leading to $T' = -\frac{1}{20} + \frac{x}{10\sqrt{x^2+15^2}}$

Extreme values can be found by setting $T'=0~~~~==>~~2x = \sqrt{x^2+15^2}$

Solve for x.

Comment: As in the other answer, you might want to take the second derivative to check which of the two values for x is the minima. But in this case x will be a positive and negative number of the same magnitude and it is obvious which one is the minima. But just in case you are required to show it, you'll need the 2nd derivative.